# Rails Tutorial : Test code

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a question regarding the famous [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org) book. I'm following the [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org) up to Chapter 3. The problem come when I try to generate a test code in [Listing 3.9](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code-home_page_content_spec)

The code generated by my system is :

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "StaticPages" do
  describe "GET /static_pages" do
    it "works! (now write some real specs)" do
      # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat methods/matchers
      get static_pages_index_path
      response.status.should be(200)
    end
  end
end
```

And as you can see, it's pretty different with the code generated in [Listing 3.9](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#code-home_page_content_spec)

So, any idea what is happening? Should I use my code or code in Listing 3.9 to continue the tutorial?

I use Rails 4.0 and Ruby 2.0, same with the author's version in the tutorial.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Usually, you use the code from your tutorial, since you are "coding" the tutorial aren't you? And `(now write some real specs)` should IMHO be self-explanatory ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just sample code that the system generates whenever you create a new integration test file. It is irrelevant.

You can delete it, and move along with the code in the tutorial.